# Handle Production Migrations and Development Migrations in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

While developing a Django project, all your migrations are stored within each app folder, however, in production I don't want those migrations, I want to keep a `Production` database, and a `Development` database:

**How do I handle Django migrations in a Production and Development environment?**

I'm asking this question because it's been really hard to update my deployed project with new additions in the development one, my ideal scenario would be to keep each set of migrations in a folder outside my source code, just like the databases.

Comment: you can't just change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment var to point to a "development" or "production" settings module that changes the `DATABASES` setting? Then you can use dev or prod database. Or just use source version management like git to keep a "production" and "development" branch.

Comment: the best idea is to keep production and development migrations the same and while developing you clean migrations before pushing the code. https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide
https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/
Check out these links

Comment: @CharanjitSingh what you meant by "clear migrations"?

Comment: By clean migrations I mean in development, you might end up deleting a table and re-creating it so make sure you don't push the un-intended migrations. The thing is you should treat migrations as code, not an automated script. I have done a lot of mistakes in the past, so, I came to the conclusion of including migrations in code. and that's effective and gives more control. 

Moreover you might have to do data migrations in production, how will you do if you wont push the code?

Comment: Thanks @hldev, spent the last day, and implemented modularity through the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, and it was way easier to deploy.

Comment: Thanks @CharanjitSingh, I've looked at the style guide you referenced and I agree with you on migrations, you should push untended migrations to your production code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best idea is to keep production and development migrations the same and while developing you clean migrations before pushing the code and **you should push migrations** into your Version Control System too.

In development, you might end up deleting a table and re-creating it so make sure you don't push the un-intended migrations. The thing is **you should treat migrations as code, not an automated script**. I have done a lot of mistakes in the past, so, I came to the conclusion of including migrations in code. and that's effective and gives more control.

Moreover you might have to do **data migrations** in production, how will you do if you wont push the code?

Comment: Do you have any further reading on this subject you can reference? In my experience, migrations generated from development cannot safely be pushed to prod because they may corrupt the production database. I find it easier to generate the migrations in prod, add them to git, and then pull them down in development. However, I have not yet reconciled how to clean my local dev database with the prod migrations.

Comment: When using containers, this approach don't work, I guess it's better to test on staging environment as well before pushing everything to production. (even the migrations)

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide